# data is not updating in Database real-time using windows service

Tags: c#, mysql, windows-services

I have written a windows service to get data from a CSV file and write them back to the database. It is working smoothly as I expected. But there is an issue with updating the data. My intention is to get update the changes of the CSV file back to database right away. Although my windows service runs in background when I change the data in the csv file it won't update the database for some reason. I even tried to restart the windows service. But no luck that either. I can insert my coding down below.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Timers;
using MySql.Data;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace abpservice
{
    public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
    {
        private Timer timer1 = null;



        public Service1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public void onDebug()
            {
                OnStart(null);
            }
        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            timer1 = new Timer();
            this.timer1.Interval = 30000; //every 30 seconds
            this.timer1.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(this.timer1_Tick);
            timer1.Enabled = true;
            library.WriteErrorLog("windows service started");
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            string connStr = "server=localhost;user=root;database=database;port=3306;password=123456";
            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);

            MySqlBulkLoader bl = new MySqlBulkLoader(conn);
            bl.TableName = "jobs";
            bl.FieldTerminator = ",";
            bl.LineTerminator = "\n";
            bl.FileName = @"C:\Users\source\repos\WindowsService1\WindowsService1\bin\Debug\jobs.csv";

            //bl.FileName = bl.FileName.Replace(@"\\", @"\ \");
            bl.NumberOfLinesToSkip = 1;

            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Connecting to MySQL...");
                conn.Open();

                // Upload data from file
                int count = bl.Load();
                Console.WriteLine(count + " lines uploaded.");





                conn.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Done.");
            library.WriteErrorLog("Timer ticked and some  jobs have been done sucessfully");
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            timer1.Enabled = false;
            library.WriteErrorLog("Test window service stopped");
        }
    }
}
```

If someone could catch why the changes in the CSV file did not get updated real-time in the database please do not hesitate to put an answer. That might help me a lot to finish this task.

Comment: Watch the file for modifications, then import if it changed.

Comment: @tadman Hey thanks for your answer. Can I use LastWriteTime Property for this purpose. Thank you!